# Error al enviar Correo LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

Al ejecutar una función que envía un correo electrónico me lanza este error sin embargo envía el correo satisfactoriamente, solo bota el error al continuar la función 
ERROR:

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \
>   FatalThrowableError (E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR) Type error: Argument 2
>   passed to Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::send() must be of the type array,
>   string given, called in
>   /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php
>   on line 221

este es mi código:

```
public function contact(Request $request){
      $data['message_'] = $request->input('message');
      $subject          = $request->input('subject');
      $data['email']    = Auth::user()->email;
      $username    = Auth::user()->name;

      $result = Mail::send('emails.contact', $data , function($message) use ($data,$subject) {
          $message->from($data['email']);
          $message->to('hola@ejemplo.com')->subject($subject);
         });
      Session::flash('send','Se ha enviado correctamente el correo');
      $subject          = "Nos pondremos en contacto.";
      $resultII = Mail::send('emails.correo_soporte', $username , function($message) use ($data,$subject) {
          $message->from('hola@ejemplo.com');
          $message->to($data['email'])->subject($subject);
         });
      return back();

    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tu error, cómo lo dice la descripción, está en que el segundo parámetro del método `send` requiere de un arreglo y no de una cadena, tu error se corregiría de la siguiente forma:

```
$resultII = Mail::send('emails.correo_soporte', ['username' => $username] , function($message) use ($data,$subject) {
          $message->from('hola@ejemplo.com');
          $message->to($data['email'])->subject($subject);
         });
```

En la vista de tu correo puedes usar la variable como `$username` ya que existe una llave llamada `'username'` en tu array.

**NOTA:** En tu primer correo enviado no generó error ya que **SI** le estás enviando un array al segundo parámetro del método `send`.